# How to implement an pure-CSS flag-shape container?

Tags: css, css-shapes

My target is to implement a pure-CSS flag-shape container like this:

[image]

Requirements include:

- `background-color` of parent container is unknown
- works for different `line-height` and `font-size` settings

Comment: "`background-color` of parent container is unknown",  but this full will be pink, yes?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov in this case I mean `white` for its parent container, while itself is pink.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Option 1

Use [`clip-path`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path), but check browser support for this property:

```css
div {
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 85% 50%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
  
  background-color: #ff69b4;

  /* styles for demo */
  padding: 20px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div>5 items</div>
```

#### Option 2

Use SVG:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <polygon points="0 0, 100 0, 85 50, 100 100, 0 100" fill="#ff69b4" />
</svg>
```

#### Option 3

Use absolutely positioned pseudoelements with gradients (to simulate triangles)

```css
div {
  background-color: #ff69b4;
  margin-right: 50px;
  position: relative;

  /* styles for demo */
  padding: 20px;
  color: #fff;
}

/* pseudoelement to simulate triangles */
div:before,
div:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left top, transparent 50%, #ff69b4 50%);
}

/* Flip triangle */
div:after {
  top: 50%;
  transform: scaleY(-1);
}
```

```html
<div>5 items</div>
```

Comment: Among the three `clip-path` seems like the best choice though browser support is poor(https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path). Pseudo element with `linear-gradient` has pretty good compatibility(IE10+) but suffers from aliasing.

Answer (score 3):

Another possible variant would be to use transformed pseudo elements.

- Create 2 layers using `::before` ad `::after` pseudo elements.
- Add `background-color` and place them with `position: absolute` having `50%` height of the parent.
- Apply CSS3 `skew()` transformations to get the flag shape.

**Output Image:**

[image: Output Image]

**Working Demo:**

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box;}
body {
  background: linear-gradient(green, yellow) no-repeat;
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0;
}
.flag {
  padding: 5px 40px 5px 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.flag:before,
.flag:after {
  transform-origin: top right;
  transform: skewX(-45deg);
  position: absolute;
  background: pink;
  content: '';
  left: -45px;
  height: 50%;
  z-index: -1;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.flag:after {
  transform-origin: bottom right;
  transform: skewX(45deg);
  top: auto;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="flag">5 Items</div>
```